# How to print user input multiple times in multiple lines

Tags: python, user-input

so how do I print out "#"  A) times the user input and  B) in as many lines as the user input.
I now only have the A part figured out. How do I add the B?

```
width = int(input("Width: "))
height = int("input("Height: "))
mark = "#" * width

print(mark)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a loop

```
for i in range(height):
    print(mark)
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have the number of times to print in variable n:
do it like this.

```
for i in range(n):
    print(mark)
```

your code has error in it just a typo.
here..

```
width = int(input("Width: "))
height = int("input("Height: ")) --- this line
```

should be like this

```
height = int(input("Height :"))
```